# PHP file is deprecated?

Tags: php, error-handling, server

On my server, the following error is listed several times per day.
Can anybody tells me what it means and about what file it is reporting?
[11-Apr-2021 21:01:59 America/Boise] PHP Deprecated:  Directive 'allow_url_include' is deprecated in Unknown on line 0.
TIA

Comment: When the notice refers to a **directive** as deprecated, that's referring to a configuration being set in a `ini_set()` call or a `.htaccess` or `php.ini` file. The first two you can probably find in your own code, for changes to `php.ini` you might have to contact your server administrator.

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of websites on the server using code that makes use of the allow_url_include function. This function was deprecated in PHP 7.4.
This notice is just a warning and not a fatal PHP error. Site functionality should resume as normal.

1. Downgrade the site's version of PHP.
2. Work with your website developer or system administrator to update or rewrite the code of any sites producing the warnings.
3. Disable deprecation warnings (See: https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360059474934)

As far as I know, if you have updated your PHP version, checking that everything in your .htaccess is also up to date may fix the problem. Otherwise, updating the PHP version might help.

Note that WP Engine has decided to deprecate the .htaccess file for all customers on future versions of PHP. The latest PHP version, PHP 7.4, and any subsequent versions will no longer support .htaccess.

ref: https://wpengine.com/support/htaccess-deprecation/

Comment: Does this mean that ".htaccess" will be deprecated?
And I wanted to add a password to my blog using ".htaccess"?
What now?